# what does '$' prefix in the event

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, just a question on `$event`. what does `$` prefix mean?is `$event` a special keyword that 's why I couldn't use sth else like  `$somethingElse`?

I'm from Java/C# background, could anyone name an equivalent thing in Java or C#? for example, Angular build-in directives are like ASP.NET MVC's tag helpers

Comment: Take a look [at this issue][1] raised before angular bacame stable.

There is no reason for the dollar. Basically it's there to avoid clashes with other variables like `event` which is already defined in some browsers.


  [1]: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8425

Comment: Sorry it was erroneously marked as duplicate, so I could not respond properly.